# Firefox WebExtension - issue with browser.i18n.getMessage

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

When calling `browser.i18n.getMessage('myKey')` in a Firefox WebExtension, an exception is shown in the background Console if 'myKey' does not exist:

```
   Unknown localization message myKey
```

In Chrome, it fails silently and returns an empty string.

At other times, I find that it returns a string of `??`. This is not the same as Chome.

Answer (score 0):

This was opened as a [bug here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1258199), with further discussion [here](https://reviewboard.mozilla.org/r/44093/). It looks like it will be fixed to return an empty string.